# Facebook graph API not returning all mentions

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api

I was having this problem with multiple searches, but here is one of them:

This is the post:
https://www.facebook.com/stefsasu/posts/207104452699707
that should appear in this search:
http://graph.facebook.com/search?q=mccain%20chips&type=post&locale=en_US

Am I doing something wrong?
Even if I delete the locale, the post still isn't there...

Comment: Can you detail this question more? Make it more general pls. You have a post in Facebook that doesn't show up in their graphs api?

Answer (score 3):

This search: 
http://graph.facebook.com/search?q=mccain%20chips&type=post&locale=en_US
 will not yield all the comments in Facebook that contain "mcCain chips" but rather search facebook for Applications\Pages that contain the search term. This is equivalent for searching in the little search-box on the top of FB's pages.

If you want to search in the comments of a specific user (e.g. Jake) you should fetch https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token= 
and parse the results.

If you want to parse over all of Jake's feed you need to have an **access token** (which you will get if Jake or one of his friend will install your app, assuming the friend has granted the appropriate permissions).

Click the links on this page for deeper insights on the Graph API:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Answer (score 3):

You can search over all PUBLIC objects only...Stefan Sasu account is not public...